# Change label name of options in wishlist item listing in magento

Tags: magento

I want to change option label. for ex. there is one label name 'Product Details and Comment' and i want to modify it and even want to add one `<td>` inside that, but here what i found is label comes by code 
`<?php foreach ($columns as $column): ?>
    <th><?php echo $column->getTitle();?></th>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

and i want to know from where i can set the title for label.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Hey sorry guys...i have found solution we can have it from layout xml file.

Comment: or by locale csv Mage_Wishlist.csv